# How can I run a task in Grunt using an array of filenames which are dynamically generated?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, gruntjs

I am fairly new to using Grunt but have a fairly good understanding of how tasks are installed and run. So far I am able to run everything as I want which includes minifying js, copying files and running jshint.

I now want to run 'clean' to remove files from a folder but only an array of selected files which I hope to generate dynamically.

So if I had a **dynamically generated** array e.g.

```
var deleteFilenames = ["file3.js","file2.jpg","file7.html"] etc.
```

How would I set a grunt clean task to just delete these files?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable to construct the config passed `initConfig`:

```
var deleteFilenames = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
grunt.initConfig({
    clean: deleteFilenames
});
```

In the code above, the list is static but `deleteFilenames` could be constructed from an algorithm that computes file names.

Comment: @user3197788 if you have accepted this answer you could as well vote +1 and give more love to the one who answered it. ;)

Comment: I tried but it won't let me as I have less than 15 rep

Comment: @user3197788; I'll do it then :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a wildcard token:

```
clean: ["file*"]
```

If you want something *cleaner*, you should include your `Gruntfile.js` or try to ouput your generated assets into a specific directory (such as `dist/`).

Comment: Thanks but the filenames will be different so won't have any similarities in filenames. i.e. 'image2.jpg' 'page1.html' 'video.mp4'